# Visual Studio C# EXE instead of .application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, publish

I am deploying a c# Windows Forms application to our network server. It will not need to be installed. It will only be used internally. When I publish, It creates a file **ourprogram.application**. When double clicking, I get the various checks for a non existent certificate and an annoying "Publisher cannot be verified" stall box.

What I want is to create a simple **ourprogram.exe** without all the checks. I can copy all the files under bin/release and put it in the network folder - with this method I get my .exe but I have to copy all the other files and dlls that go with it.

Isn't there a way to simply build an all inclusive **.exe**?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and .Net 4.5.1

Comment: Yes, those all inclusive exes are usually called `setup.exe` and are called "installers". If you want one file to copy everything you will need to write a installer project instead of using Click-once.

Comment: check your project properties, sign, application and publish option

Comment: Make sure license terms of those extra dlls allow such use ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking to embed the dll's into a single executable, take a look at [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)

[Something like](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge)

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:SelfContainedProgram.exe 
        Program.exe ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary2.dll
```

In your project's post-build event command line should produce the single exe you are looking for.